# cascading/dependent sublist dropdown in netsuite with suitescript

Tags: netsuite, sublist

I need to implement dependent dropdown in sublist fields.
I have create Sublist using `form.addSubList();`
in suitelet and added two select fields in the sublist. with setScript() calling client script for some validations and inserting values.
The two select fields should be dependent. For instance if i have two select fields of  primary dropdown and secondary drop down respectively, In primary dropdown list may be of Travel,country the second select field should be dynamically popluated based on the slection on first option. If I selected Travel then second select field should show the dropdown values : Travel-Domestiv, Travel- International and if country selected it should be Argentina,Belgium,India.
To get this i implemented on field change,using nlapiInsertLineItemOption and nlapiRemovetLineItemOption I updated the values.But when the next line is updating the values are overwritten with second selection. Please help me how can i store the values or id it posible to diable/ hide the drop in sublist field based on selection or it can possible by psot sourcing.

Code snippet :

```
if(primary_selected == '1')//primary_selected dropdown:Travel and Country
{
      nlapiRemoveLineItemOption('custpage_other_cost_sublist_plan', 'custpage_secondary_plan_items'); //remove all existing select options 
            nlapiInsertLineItemOption('custpage_other_cost_sublist_plan', 'custpage_secondary_plan_items', '', '',true);
            nlapiInsertLineItemOption('custpage_other_cost_sublist_plan', 'custpage_secondary_plan_items', '1', 'Domestic',false);
            nlapiInsertLineItemOption('custpage_other_cost_sublist_plan', 'custpage_secondary_plan_items', '2', 'International',false);
            nlapiInsertLineItemOption('custpage_other_cost_sublist_plan', 'custpage_secondary_plan_items', '3', 'Others',false);

        }
        else
        {
            if(primary_selected == '3')
            {

            nlapiRemoveLineItemOption('custpage_other_cost_sublist_plan', 'custpage_secondary_plan_items'); //remove all existing select options 
            nlapiInsertLineItemOption('custpage_other_cost_sublist_plan', 'custpage_secondary_plan_items', '', '',true);
            nlapiInsertLineItemOption('custpage_other_cost_sublist_plan', 'custpage_secondary_plan_items', '4', 'Argentina',false);
            nlapiInsertLineItemOption('custpage_other_cost_sublist_plan', 'custpage_secondary_plan_items', '5', 'Belgium',false);
            //nlapiInsertLineItemOption('custpage_other_cost_sublist_plan', 'custpage_secondary_plan_items', '6', 'India');
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're trying to do is possible inside of the sublist. You might look into creating an Assistant type solution where the user walks through a "wizard" type of application. The assistant can store values as you rebuild the page at each step.

Comment: Thank so much for your response. Could you please brief it. I didn't get the complete view.